# Run phone-only app on iPad with 4.7 inch resolution

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, resolution

I have an iPhone-only app that i want to test on a real device. Yet the device available is New iPad 9.7 inch. How can i test the app on that iPad but with higher resolution than iPhone 4 (iphone 5, 6 and 6 plus).

Comment: iPhone only apps run at iPhone 4 resolution on all iPads. The only way to get a different resolution on an iPad is to make your app a universal app.

Answer (score 0):

In the project setting -> General -> Deployment info:Change the "devices" setting from iPhone to Universal.
Is it what your mean?